# Using PHPs SoapClient to to consume a WCF API

Tags: php, wcf, soap-client

I've been trying to consume a WCF API for the first time, using PHPs SoapClient, but so far no lock.

[WSDL is copied here](http://pastebin.com/ssim1grN)

The begin, I need to retrieve a token from the `LOGIN` function, and use this token when calling other functions. Login details are:

- Username: 'regular'
- Passord: '' (blank, not NULL)

So far I've tried number of combinations, usually something like this:

```
<?php

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

$params  = array(
    "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
    "trace" => 1,
    "exceptions" => 0,
);

$client = new SoapClient('http://bibjure.rwaao.no:8001/Jussystemer/BibjureService?singleWsdl', $params);

$retval = $client->Login('regular','');

if (is_soap_fault($retval)) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$retval->faultcode}, faultstring: {$retval->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}

var_dump($retval);
```

Which results in the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  SOAP Fault: (faultcode: s:Sender, faultstring: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.) in /mnt/data/fredrik/wcf-test.php on line 17`

I have no idea how to address this error. I'm hoping that someone might see the error in my code.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add soap headers and try something like this. It may work

```
        $client = new SoapClient('http://bibjure.rwaao.no:8001/Jussystemer/BibjureService?singleWsdl', $params);

        $actionHeader = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing','Action','http://tempuri.org/IService/GetData',true);
        $client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);

        $retval = $client->Login('regular','');
```

Comment: Same error still. I'm guessing that the parameters in `SoapHeader` needs to be modified. Unfortunately I have no idea to what.

Comment: @frigg Yeah u have to modify  the parameters in the header. Take this as a sample. $auth = array(
        'UserName'=>'USERNAME',
        'Password'=>'PASSWORD',
        'SystemId'=> array('_'=>'DATA','Param'=>'PARAM'),
        );
  $header = new SoapHeader('NAMESPACE','Auth',$auth,false);$client->__setSoapHeaders($header );